# Comparing a list of names and a column in excel file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a txt file (file1) that contains a list of protein names and an excel file in which the second column contains a bigger list of protein names. I want to go through both of these two lists and to determine whether the proteins from file1 are presented in the xlsx file. So if there is a row in xlsx that corresponds to a protein from file1 than I want the row to be colored. Here is some code I've made.

```
for line in file1:
    for i in range(2,worksheet.max_row):
        if line.split('|')[1] == worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value:
            worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2).fill = PatternFill(fill_type='solid', start_color='ff8327', end_color='ff8327')
```

But the code doesn't work properly. It makes one loop for the first protein name and then just stops without going firther. 
And there is one more problem, I would like to make the procedure faster.

If someone knows any way of solving the problem please share.

Best,

Maria

Comment: Plese tag your question with the name of the third-party module you're using to read the xlsx files.

Comment: Going in the same direction, please consult [mcve] to check what you need for a question that is fully understandable without additional background questions.

Comment: Code looks correct. To get what is wrong add ```print(f"Comparing {line.split('|')[1]} with {worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value}, {i=}")``` above the if statement.

Comment: Please tell us more about what you want to have in the end - do you want to have the protein that are in both columns in one list, do you want a separate indicator in another column, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have both columns as a list, you can either use a list comprehension or even a set operations to obtain a list of proteins that is in your text file as well as in your excel-file:

```py
file1 = ["ABCD1", "PTEN", "MMP13"]

excel = ["ABCD1", "AKT3", "PTEN", "SOCS3", "SIRT1"]

# List comprehension
intersect = [protein for protein in file1 if protein in excel]
print(intersect)

['ABCD1', 'PTEN']

# Set operation

intersect_set = list(set(file1)&set(excel))
print(intersect_set)

['ABCD1', 'PTEN']
```

Based on this obtained list, you might be then able to colour your proteins in excel.

```py
for i in range(2,worksheet.max_row):
    protein = worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
    if protein in intersect:
            worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2).fill = PatternFill(fill_type='solid', start_color='ff8327', end_color='ff8327')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid one for loop, by storing the data from txt file into array as follows

```
file1 = open('test2.txt', 'r')
lines = [line.rstrip('\n').split('|')[1] for line in file1]
file1.close()
for i in range(2,worksheet.max_row):
    if worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value in lines:
        worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2).fill = PatternFill(fill_type='solid', start_color='ff8327', end_color='ff8327')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a set of the protein names in the text file to compare. Your code is incomplete so you may need to make some changes to this to get it to work.

Assuming the text file has rows like this this "SOMETHING|PROTEIN"

```
with open('proteins.txt', 'r') as src:
    proteins = {line.split("|")[1] for line in src.readlines()}

#Define the fill
fill = PatternFill(fill_type='solid', start_color='ff8327', end_color='ff8327')

#check the cells in column B and assign the fill
for cell in ws['B']:
    if cell.value in proteins:
        cell.fill = fill
```